# Django adding model id to URL

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have a dashboard that lists locations. You can then click on locations to get more details of that location. I am getting a 404 error message though.

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/locations/get//
```

Heres the part of the code I am having issues with.

urls.py

```
url(r'^accounts/loggedin/locations/all/$', 'assessments.views.locations'),
url(r'^accounts/loggedin/locations/get/(?P<location_id>\d+)/$', 'assessments.views.location'),
```

views.py

```
def locations(request):
    return render_to_response('dashboard/locations.html', {'locations': Location.objects.all() })

def location(request, location_id=1):
    return render_to_response('dashboard/location.html', {'location': Location.objects.get(id=location_id) })
```

locations.html

```
{% for p in locations %}
    <tr>
        <td><a href="/locations/get/{{ location.id }}/">{{ p.landlord_agent }}</a></td>
        <td><a href="/locations/get/{{ location.id }}/">{{ p.id }}</a></td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

To be honest I don't get why it would be location_id, as the database field is just id but thats how the guide showed me to do it and changing it to just id doesn't seem to make a difference

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is inside the template. You are having a loop variable called `p`, not `location`.

Replace `location.id` with `p.id`.

---

Or, better have this variable called `location` - more readable and explicit.

Complete template code:

```
{% for location in locations %}
    <tr>
        <td><a href="/locations/get/{{ location.id }}/">{{ location.landlord_agent }}</a></td>
        <td><a href="/locations/get/{{ location.id }}/">{{ location.id }}</a></td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

edit your app/urls.py:

```
url(r'^locations/get/(?P<location_id>[\d]+)/$', 'assessments.views.location')
```